# Fill remaining page with image

Tags: graphics, vertical, fill

I hope to fill the remaining vertical space with an image. This has been done here; https://blogs.gnome.org/muelli/2011/04/perfectly-scale-an-image-to-the-rest-of-a-page-with-latex/

However I cant figure out how this is done. I am not very used to macros. 
I simply hope that something like this exists;

```
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth,keepaspectratio=true,
                 height= "Vertical space remaining" ]{figure.fig}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can mark the bases of lines as "labels" using [`zref`](//ctan.org/pkg/zref)'s `savepos` module. This allows you to do calculations on the (x and) y coordinates of the labels. The command `\filltopageendgraphics[<options>]{<file>}` below automates this process (assuming you'll only have one such image on any given page).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{zref-savepos,graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% \filltopageendgraphics[<options>]{<file>}
\newcommand{\filltopageendgraphics}[2][]{%
  \par
  \zsaveposy{top-\thepage}% Mark (baseline of) top of image
  \vfill
  \zsaveposy{bottom-\thepage}% Mark (baseline of) bottom of image
  \smash{\includegraphics[height=\dimexpr\zposy{top-\thepage}sp-\zposy{bottom-\thepage}sp\relax,#1]{#2}}%
  \par
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\filltopageendgraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}

\clearpage

\lipsum[2]

\filltopageendgraphics[width=.6\linewidth]{example-image-b}

\clearpage

\lipsum[1-3]

\filltopageendgraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image-c}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey thanks, this does seem to do what I hoped to achieve. Now I do like to implement it in a figure, so be i'll able to add Captions, labels, centring and position. As in

`\begin{figure}[h]%!t
    \centering  \filltopageendgraphics[keepaspectratio=true]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig: example}

\end{figure}`

Comment: @JanvanWilligen: That type of question had been asked before. Will see if I can find it. Otherwise I'd suggest asking [a follow-up question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117/5764) pointing back to this one.

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to horizontally center the image? Is there a quick and easy way to do that?

Comment: @Logan: Indeed. It just sets the image like any other character of a paragraph. If you want it to not have the regular paragraph indent, insert `\noindent` before the `\smash` so it doesn't have an indent. This way it'll be flush with the left text margin.