# Horizontally centering and vertically filling svg

Tags: tcolorbox, alignment, svg, zref

I am trying to fill the remaining space of a page with a `tcbox` wrapped `includesvg` item. There is funny behavior when I do this. When including a tall svg, one which will not fill the entire width of the image, it's spacing behaves weirdly. Sometimes it overlaps the text, sometimes it fits, but never does it appear to have proper vertical spacing with the parskip below the last paragraph. When I use a wide image, one which will fill the width of the text before it resizes to fill the rest of the vertical space, it will always bleed into the right margin.

So, I ultimately have two questions

1. I believe the bleeding in the right margins is due to `tcbox` default padding. I'd like that padding, so how do I accommodate for that in that macro?
2. How do I fix the vertical filling to have proper spacing in all cases?

Here is MWE with three files..

main.tex

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}

\newcommand{\filltopageendsvg}[2][]{%
  \par
  \zsaveposy{top-\thepage}% Mark (baseline of) top of image
  \vfill
  \zsaveposy{bottom-\thepage}% Mark (baseline of) bottom of image
  \begin{center}
    \smash{%
      \tcbox[colframe=black]{%
        \includesvg[height=\dimexpr\zposy{top-\thepage}sp-\zposy{bottom-\thepage}sp\relax,#1]{#2}%
      }
    }%
  \end{center}
  \par
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{The First Chapter}

\lipsum[1]

\filltopageendsvg[width=\textwidth]{tall.svg}

\newpage

\lipsum[1]

\chapter{The Second Chapter}

\lipsum[1]

\filltopageendsvg[width=\textwidth]{wide.svg}

\end{document}
```

tall.svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   width="60.288326mm"
   height="74.001808mm"
   viewBox="0 0 60.288326 74.001808"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg5"
   sodipodi:docname="tall.svg"
   inkscape:version="1.1.2 (0a00cf5339, 2022-02-04)"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="namedview7"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pagecheckerboard="0"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:zoom="1.2516522"
     inkscape:cx="51.531887"
     inkscape:cy="152.5983"
     inkscape:window-width="2560"
     inkscape:window-height="1007"
     inkscape:window-x="0"
     inkscape:window-y="1168"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1" />
  <defs
     id="defs2" />
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(-50.232845,-69.50075)">
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-size:2.82223px;line-height:1.25;font-family:'Roboto Slab';-inkscape-font-specification:'Roboto Slab';text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.264583"
       x="79.86335"
       y="71.507179"
       id="text2168"><tspan
         sodipodi:role="line"
         id="tspan2166"
         style="text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.264583"
         x="79.86335"
         y="71.507179">Top</tspan></text>
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-size:2.82223px;line-height:1.25;font-family:'Roboto Slab';-inkscape-font-specification:'Roboto Slab';text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.264583"
       x="79.869553"
       y="143.47362"
       id="text3612"><tspan
         sodipodi:role="line"
         id="tspan3610"
         style="text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.264583"
         x="79.869553"
         y="143.47362">Bottom</tspan></text>
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-size:2.82223px;line-height:1.25;font-family:'Roboto Slab';-inkscape-font-specification:'Roboto Slab';text-align:start;text-anchor:start;stroke-width:0.264583"
       x="50.121223"
       y="107.71261"
       id="text3718"><tspan
         sodipodi:role="line"
         id="tspan3716"
         style="text-align:start;text-anchor:start;stroke-width:0.264583"
         x="50.121223"
         y="107.71261">Left</tspan></text>
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-size:2.82223px;line-height:1.25;font-family:'Roboto Slab';-inkscape-font-specification:'Roboto Slab';text-align:start;text-anchor:start;stroke-width:0.264583"
       x="103.42839"
       y="107.41151"
       id="text6148"><tspan
         sodipodi:role="line"
         id="tspan6146"
         style="text-align:start;text-anchor:start;stroke-width:0.264583"
         x="103.42839"
         y="107.41151">Right</tspan></text>
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-size:2.82223px;line-height:1.25;font-family:'Roboto Slab';-inkscape-font-specification:'Roboto Slab';text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.264583"
       x="79.85508"
       y="107.71261"
       id="text7480"><tspan
         sodipodi:role="line"
         id="tspan7478"
         style="text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.264583"
         x="79.85508"
         y="107.71261">Tall</tspan></text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

wide.svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   width="85.159164mm"
   height="36.117317mm"
   viewBox="0 0 85.159164 36.117317"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg5"
   sodipodi:docname="wide.svg"
   inkscape:version="1.1.2 (0a00cf5339, 2022-02-04)"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="namedview7"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pagecheckerboard="0"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:zoom="1.2516522"
     inkscape:cx="117.84424"
     inkscape:cy="56.725023"
     inkscape:window-width="2560"
     inkscape:window-height="1007"
     inkscape:window-x="0"
     inkscape:window-y="1168"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1" />
  <defs
     id="defs2" />
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(-50.232845,-89.891085)">
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-size:2.82223px;line-height:1.25;font-family:'Roboto Slab';-inkscape-font-specification:'Roboto Slab';text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.264583"
       x="92.298759"
       y="91.897514"
       id="text2168"><tspan
         sodipodi:role="line"
         id="tspan2166"
         style="text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.264583"
         x="92.298759"
         y="91.897514">Top</tspan></text>
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-size:2.82223px;line-height:1.25;font-family:'Roboto Slab';-inkscape-font-specification:'Roboto Slab';text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.264583"
       x="92.304962"
       y="125.97946"
       id="text3612"><tspan
         sodipodi:role="line"
         id="tspan3610"
         style="text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.264583"
         x="92.304962"
         y="125.97946">Bottom</tspan></text>
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-size:2.82223px;line-height:1.25;font-family:'Roboto Slab';-inkscape-font-specification:'Roboto Slab';text-align:start;text-anchor:start;stroke-width:0.264583"
       x="50.121223"
       y="109.16071"
       id="text3718"><tspan
         sodipodi:role="line"
         id="tspan3716"
         style="text-align:start;text-anchor:start;stroke-width:0.264583"
         x="50.121223"
         y="109.16071">Left</tspan></text>
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-size:2.82223px;line-height:1.25;font-family:'Roboto Slab';-inkscape-font-specification:'Roboto Slab';text-align:start;text-anchor:start;stroke-width:0.264583"
       x="128.29922"
       y="108.8596"
       id="text6148"><tspan
         sodipodi:role="line"
         id="tspan6146"
         style="text-align:start;text-anchor:start;stroke-width:0.264583"
         x="128.29922"
         y="108.8596">Right</tspan></text>
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-size:2.82223px;line-height:1.25;font-family:'Roboto Slab';-inkscape-font-specification:'Roboto Slab';text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.264583"
       x="92.315987"
       y="109.14623"
       id="text7480"><tspan
         sodipodi:role="line"
         id="tspan7478"
         style="text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.264583"
         x="92.315987"
         y="109.14623">Wide</tspan></text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Somewhat related to, but expanding on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/502129/fill-remaining-page-with-image).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I have not answered my initial question, I have discovered a better solution. When scouring the tcolorbox documentation, I found the option `fill height` and the exposed property `\tcbtextheight`. Combining these the following solution is much cleaner and achieves my desired output...

```latex
\documentclass[draft]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}
\usepackage{showframe}

\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\begin{document}

\chapter{The First Chapter}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{tcolorbox}[height fill]
  \centering
  \includesvg[height=\tcbtextheight,width=\linewidth]{tall.svg}
\end{tcolorbox}

\clearpage

\chapter{The Second Chapter}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{tcolorbox}[height fill]
  \centering
  \includesvg[height=\tcbtextheight,width=\linewidth]{wide.svg}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Even better, `halign` and `valign` options can be used in the `tcolorbox` environment.